# Can you use Decision Tables in Relational Databases

Tags: database

I heard that decision tables in relational database have been researched a lot in academia. I also know that business rules engines use decision tables and that many BPMS use them as well. 
I was wondering if people today use decision tables within their relational databases?

Comment: What?  Are you talking about modeling a decision table in a database?  Or are you talking about a BPEL engine using decision tables to process data in a database?  Could you focus the question a little?

Comment: modeling a decision table in a database

Comment: Could you rewrite the question to reflect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decision table is a cluster of conditions and actions.  A condition can be simple enough that you can represent it with a simple "match a column against this value" string.  Or a condition could be hellishly complex.  An action, similarly, could be as simple as "move this value to a column".  Or the action could involve multiple parts or steps or -- well -- anything.

A CASE function in a SELECT or WHERE clause *is* a decision table.  This is the first example of decision table "in" a relational database.

You can have a "transformation" table with columns that have old-value and replacement-value.  You can then write a small piece of code like the following.

```
def decision_table( aRow ):
    result= connection.execute( "SELECT replacement_value FROM transformation WHERE old_value = ?", aRow['somecolumn'] )
    replacement= result.fetchone()
    aRow['anotherColumn']= result['replacement_value']
```

Each row of the decision table has a "match this old_value" and "move this replacement_value" kind of definition.

The "condition" parts of a decision table have to be evaluated somewhere.  Your application is where this will happen.  You will fetch the condition values from the database.  You'll use those values in some function(s) to see if the rule is true.

The "action" parts of a decision table have to be executed somewhere; again, your application does stuff.  You'll fetch action values from the database.  You'll use those values to insert, update or delete other values.

Decision tables are used all the time; they've always been around in relational databases.  Each table requires a highly customized data model.  It also requires a unique condition function and action procedure.

It doesn't generalize well.  If you want, you could store XML in the database and invoke some rules engine to interpret and execute the BPEL rules.  In this case, the rules engine does the condition and action processing.

If you want, you could store Python (or Tcl or something else) in the database.  Seriously.  You'd write the conditions and actions in Python.  You'd fetch it from the database and run the Python code fragment.

Lots of choices.  None of the "academic".  Indeed, the basic condition - action stuff is done all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Wheter or not to put decision tables in a database depends on a number of other questions.

Will your conditions be calculated inside the RDBMS or elsewhere? If the data used for evaluating these conditions, and a suitable method for evaluating them inside the RDBMS can be devised, it is probably a good idea. Maybe your actions also happens inside your database, which would make it even more attractive.

Your conditions, and even execution of your actions might be on the outside of the RDBMS, but you could still keep the connections between combinations of conditions and actions on the inside. Probably because most of you other data is there, and all you have is a web server sitting on top of it.

I can think of two ways to model this, depending on how many conditions you have (and wheter they are binary), and what the capacity for columns per table is.

Let's say you have 6 conditions that are binary, this means you have 2^6 = 64 possible combinations. Then you could have one column for every combination, and one row for every action.

Or you could have 16 conditions which means you would have almost an incalculable number of combinations (actually 65536). Which is a ridiculous number of columns. Better then to have a column for each condition and a column for each action and 65536 rows of what to do in each possible situation. Each row would represent a situation and what to do in that situation. The only datatype you use would be bool. You could also package these bools into bitmasked integers.

Actually, bigger decision tables are better avoided. Divide and rule, and use more tables is a much better way. Usually a subject matter expert will get tired if asked to give opinions on too high a number of conditions.

The strength of the decision table is really in the modelling stage where the developer and the subject matter expert can find out if every possible situation is mapped, and no blind spots can exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think they will contribute to the already too much declined state of what used to be "in-person" communications- enough hide behind the screen as it is..... come out of the closet, get out - got the picture.

Answer (score -1):

I would look into using an Object database rather than a traditional RDBMS (Relational Database Management System). Object databases are designed to be fast at handling hierarchical relationships between objects, whereas in an RDBMS, you have to represent these relationships across multiple table rows, or even tables so your queries (tree traversals) will be slow.